# IllegalArgumentException, path separatos. The application takes .xml.xml

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, illegalargumentexception, path-separator

I have an activity which needs to modify the SharedPreferences.

```
public class AddingEmail extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener{   

    private String newMail;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private PreferenceManager prefMan;
    private EditText emailAdd;
    private EditText emailDel;
    private ArrayList<String> prefList;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addingemail);
    Log.d("On Addig EMAIL ACTIVITY","on Create");

    String name = "com.example.daemon3_preferences";
    prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And this is the PreferenceScreen..

```
public class PreferencesScreen extends PreferenceFragment{

    private final String TAG = "PreferencesScreen";
    private Set<String> emails;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate");

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
```

And I have this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /data/data/com.example.daemon3/shared_prefs/com.example.daemon3_preferences.xml.xml contains a path separator

Why it takes .xml.xml instead of .xml?

Comment: Are you opening the shared preferences anywhere else and if so can you post a snippet?  If not, clear your app data and see if you still get the same exception.

Comment: Do you mean this edit I made? the PreferenceFragment where the preferences are added from the resource?
I cleaned up everything several times and removing the app and stalling it again. 
I get the same error in the emulator and in the real device.

Comment: I mean, do you explicitly call `getSharedPreferences` anywhere else?

Comment: No, that is the only place I call it in the whole application.

Comment: Instead of calling `this.getSharedPreferences` try `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)`  PreferenceFragments save their settings to the default so maybe this will cut out your error.

Comment: Yes, using that call it works, still don't know why didn't work the other one but at least the program is running.
Thank you MCeley!

Comment: It might've been because it was trying to create a shared preferences file that conflicts with the one the preference manager was creating.  I'll break my answer out into a response so that others can benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking out the comment thread into a formal answer here.

---

Instead of calling

```
String name = "com.example.daemon3_preferences";
prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

call this:

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

`PreferenceFragment` saves your settings with the `PreferenceManager` so by attempting to open the default preferences with `getSharedPreferences`, you might be interfering with the `PreferenceManager` which could be causing that particular exception.

Comment: Yes, it worked good. I had to change "this" for getApplicationContext() but now it works. Thank you!